# Did the Facebook robots both want everything but the balls?

Tags: chat-bots

According to [this article](http://www.independent.co.uk/life-style/gadgets-and-tech/news/facebook-artificial-intelligence-ai-chatbot-new-language-research-openai-google-a7869706.html), two Facebook ai's had the following "creepy" negotiation over a transaction:

> Bob: i can i i everything else . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
>
> Alice: balls have zero to me to me to me to me to me to me to me to me to
>
> Bob: you i everything else . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
>
> Alice: balls have a ball to me to me to me to me to me to me to me
>
> Bob: i i can i i i everything else . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
>
> Alice: balls have a ball to me to me to me to me to me to me to me
>
> Bob: i . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
>
> Alice: balls have zero to me to me to me to me to me to me to me to me to
>
> Bob: you i i i i i everything else . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
>
> Alice: balls have 0 to me to me to me to me to me to me to me to me to
>
> Bob: you i i i everything else . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
>
> Alice: balls have zero to me to me to me to me to me to me to me to me to

If we first look at Bob's, he's asking for what he wants by proposing that he have all items but one and not revealing which is the one he doesn't want.  By design or by chance, this is actually a strong negotiating technique because he reveals nothing other than the fact he is willing to come to an agreement.

Alice appears to either ask for no balls, or to say they have no value to her and then obsess about things coming to her, perhaps iterating on the other items.  She would appear to be the better communicator because she at least gets to the point of saying "have a ball".  But she refuses to give anything away beyond that.

But Bob seems to stand firm saying he wants "everything else" but not giving away what he is willing to go without.

Perhaps these two are not such bad negotiators after all?

Comment: Scientifically,am not convinced by this statement "Facebook abandoned an experiment after two artificially intelligent programs appeared to be chatting to each other in a strange language only they understood." This was just a programming error.Because media is just posting even bugs in program.and remember very few have have deep understanding of this field,so we should open up our deep minds and be self aware.Billionaire company to abandon such research.Imagine?we have to open your Minds,please! Also we are not here to discuss what Facebook has failed to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if you've gone through [FAIR's blog post](https://code.facebook.com/posts/1686672014972296/deal-or-no-deal-training-ai-bots-to-negotiate/) about these negotiating bots and the research behind them.

> Did the Facebook robots both want everything but the balls?

Yes. You are right.  You can refer to the gif in FAIR's blog post. Here, the chat goes on between 2 bots, where one wants only balls, and the other offers 1 ball and a hat. And this bot re-iterates that it wants only the balls. And they negotiate for some time till they reach a consensus.

> Perhaps these two are not such bad negotiators after all?

The fact that the FAIR labs have [open-sourced the code](https://github.com/facebookresearch/end-to-end-negotiator) means that they came a fairly long way in this research.  They also [published the research paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.05125). The example on the repo's README also cites the balls-and-hats negotiation example.